# .NET: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Automapper'

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, filenotfoundexception

I installed the Autmapper in my .NET (C#) project some months ago and it has always worked well, but now, suddenly, it gives me A TypeInitialitationException when trying to use the Automapper.

The InnerException is the following:

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Automapper'".

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the *Automapper* but no, it didn't solve the problem.

Here below you can read the caller code, where the exception is reported

```
public static User ConvertBDOToDataModel(UserBDO userBDO)
{
    Validate.EnsureArgumentIsNotNull(userBDO);

    return Mappings.Convert<UserBDO, User>(userBDO);
}
```

Here below the **Mappings** class:

```
public static class Mappings
    {
        static Mappings()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Contract, ContractBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Contract, ContractBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<ConnectionString, ConnectionStringBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ConnectionString, ConnectionStringBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.City, CityBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.City, CityBDO>().ReverseMap();
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.City, DTO.CRM.CityDTO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.City, DTO.CRM.CityDTO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.Country, CountryBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.Country, CountryBDO>().ReverseMap();
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.Country, DTO.CRM.CountryDTO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.DataModel.UserModel.Country, DTO.CRM.CountryDTO>().ReverseMap();

            MapProductModelToBDO();
            MapProductBDOToModel();

            MapProductCategoryModelToBDO();
            MapProductCategoryBDOToModel();

            MapIvaModelToBDO();
            MapIvaBDOToModel();

            MapProductSupplierModelToBDO();
            MapProductSupplierBDOToModel();

            MapProductPictureModelToBDO();
            MapProductPictureBDOToModel();

            MapTagModelToBDO();
            MapTagBDOToModel();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Offer, OfferBDO>().ForMember(o => o.Contact, p => p.Ignore());
            Mapper.CreateMap<Offer, OfferBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOffer, PersonProductOfferBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOffer, PersonProductOfferBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferParagraph, PersonOfferParagraphBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferParagraph, PersonOfferParagraphBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.Person, PersonBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.Person, PersonBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Lead, LeadBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Lead, LeadBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.City, CityBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.City, CityBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonNote, PersonNoteBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonNote, PersonNoteBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyNote, CompanyNoteBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyNote, CompanyNoteBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Company, CompanyBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Company, CompanyBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.City, CityBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.City, CityBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDataBDO, PersonOfferBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDataBDO, PersonOfferBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonProductOfferDataBDO, PersonProductOfferBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonProductOfferDataBDO, PersonProductOfferBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonOfferParagraphBDO, FlatOfferParagraphBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonOfferParagraphBDO, FlatOfferParagraphBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonOfferBDO, FlatOfferBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonOfferBDO, FlatOfferBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<ContactBDO, Contact>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ContactBDO, Contact>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonBDO, EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.Person>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonBDO, EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.Model.CRM.Person>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDataBDO, OfferBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDataBDO, OfferBDO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOfferDataBDO, ProductOfferBDO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOfferDataBDO, ProductOfferBDO>();

            //Mapper.CreateMap<CustomOfferProductBDO, CustomOfferProduct>();
            //Mapper.CreateMap<CustomOfferProductBDO, CustomOfferProduct>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferBDO, Bullettin>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinTitle, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferTitle))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinText, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferText));

            Mapper.CreateMap<Bullettin, OfferBDO>()
                .ForMember(o => o.Contact, p => p.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferTitle, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinTitle))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferText, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinText))
                .BeforeMap((s, d) => d.DocumentType = Infrastructure.DocumentType.Bullettin)
                ;

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferParagraphBDO, BullettinParagraph>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferParagraphId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Bullettin, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Offer))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinProducts, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ProductOffers));

            Mapper.CreateMap<BullettinParagraph, OfferParagraphBDO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinParagraphId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Offer, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Bullettin))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductOffers, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinProducts))
                ;

            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOfferBDO, BullettinProduct>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinProductId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ProductOfferId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BullettinParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferParagraphId));

            Mapper.CreateMap<BullettinProduct, ProductOfferBDO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductOfferId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinProductId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.BullettinParagraphId))
                ;





            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferBDO, Invoice>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Number, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferTitle))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Text, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferText));

            Mapper.CreateMap<Invoice, OfferBDO>()
                .ForMember(o => o.Contact, p => p.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Number))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferTitle, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferText, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Text))
                .BeforeMap((s, d) => d.DocumentType = Infrastructure.DocumentType.Invoice)
                ;

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferParagraphBDO, InvoiceParagraph>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferParagraphId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoiceNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Invoice, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Offer))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoiceProducts, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ProductOffers))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ParagraphName))
                ;

            Mapper.CreateMap<InvoiceParagraph, OfferParagraphBDO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.InvoiceNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Offer, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Invoice))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductOffers, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.InvoiceProducts))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ParagraphName, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
                ;

            //Mapper.CreateMap<OfferParagraphBDO, InvoiceParagraph>()
            //   .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferParagraphId))
            //   .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoiceNumber, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferNumber))
            //   .ForMember(dest => dest.Invoice, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Offer))
            //   .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoiceProducts, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ProductOffers))
            //   .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ParagraphName))
            //   .ReverseMap()
            //   ;

            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOfferBDO, InvoiceProduct>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ProductOfferId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.OfferParagraphId));

            Mapper.CreateMap<InvoiceProduct, ProductOfferBDO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductOfferId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OfferParagraphId, org => org.MapFrom(src => src.ParagraphId))
                ;

            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductOfferBDO, ProductOfferBDO>();

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDocumentItem, DocumentItemDTO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDocumentItem, DocumentItemDTO>().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDocumentSection, DocumentSectionDTO>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OfferDocumentSection, DocumentSectionDTO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        public static TTargetType Convert<TToConvert, TTargetType>(TToConvert toConvert)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<TTargetType>(toConvert);
        }

        public static TTargetType DynamicConvert<TToConvert, TTargetType>(TToConvert toConvert)
        {
            return Mapper.DynamicMap<TTargetType>(toConvert);
        }

        private static void MapProductModelToBDO()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductBDO>();
        }

        private static void MapProductBDOToModel()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductBDO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        private static void MapProductCategoryModelToBDO()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductCategory, ProductCategoryBDO>();
        }

        private static void MapProductCategoryBDOToModel()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductCategory, ProductCategoryBDO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        private static void MapIvaModelToBDO()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Iva, IvaBDO>();
        }

        private static void MapIvaBDOToModel()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Iva, IvaBDO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        private static void MapProductSupplierModelToBDO()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductSupplier, ProductSupplierBDO>();
        }

        private static void MapProductSupplierBDOToModel()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductSupplier, ProductSupplierBDO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        private static void MapProductPictureModelToBDO()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductPicture, ProductPictureBDO>();
        }

        private static void MapProductPictureBDOToModel()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductPicture, ProductPictureBDO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        private static void MapTagBDOToModel()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, TagBDO>().ReverseMap();
        }

        private static void MapTagModelToBDO()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, TagBDO>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can remove your mapping code, this is nothing to do with that code. This is because for some reason automapper assemblies aren't being picked up.

Comment: fuslogvw.exe is a good tool for tracking down why your application cannot find an assembly.  The tool is a bit quirky to use, but once you get it generating the log files, it shows you in detail all the steps .NET took to try to find the application.

Comment: Software hardly ever starts to misbehave *suddenly*. Retrace your steps and figure out what you changed recently. It may be an AutoMapper version conflict in dependent assemblies.